# Lighttpd doesn't start after purging Apache

Tags: apache-2.4, lighttpd, kubuntu

I tried to migrate from Apache to Lighttpd on kubuntu 16.04. I used `apt-get remove --purge apache2` then `apt-get install lighttpd`

After running `systemctl start lighttpd` I got the error message

```
 Job for lighttpd.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status ligttpd.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

The contents of journalctl -xe is: The result is failed.

```
Mai 25 15:25:36 Heizschrank systemd[1]: lighttpd.service: Unit entered failed state.
Mai 25 15:25:36 Heizschrank systemd[1]: lighttpd.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Mai 25 15:25:36 Heizschrank systemd[1]: Reloading.
Mai 25 15:25:36 Heizschrank systemd[1]: apt-daily.timer: Adding 7h 10min 31.972833s random time.
Mai 25 15:25:36 Heizschrank systemd[1]: Started CUPS Scheduler.

-- Subject: Unit cups.service has finished start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
--
-- Unit cups.service has finished starting up.
-- 
-- The start-up result is done.

Mai 25 15:25:36 Heizschrank systemd[1]: Started ACPI event daemon.
-- Subject: Unit acpid.service has finished start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit acpid.service has finished starting up.
-- 
-- The start-up result is done.

Mai 25 15:25:41 Heizschrank sudo[22105]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
```

The output of `systemctl` status is:

```
● lighttpd.service - Lighttpd Daemon
Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/lighttpd.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mi 2016-05-25 15:25:36 CEST; 26min ago

Mai 25 15:25:36 Heizschrank systemd[1]: Starting Lighttpd Daemon...
Mai 25 15:25:36 Heizschrank lighttpd[23079]: /usr/sbin/lighttpd: symbol lookup error: /usr/sbin/lighttpd: undefined symbol: FAMNoExists
Mai 25 15:25:36 Heizschrank systemd[1]: lighttpd.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=127
Mai 25 15:25:36 Heizschrank systemd[1]: Failed to start Lighttpd Daemon.
Mai 25 15:25:36 Heizschrank systemd[1]: lighttpd.service: Unit entered failed state.
Mai 25 15:25:36 Heizschrank systemd[1]: lighttpd.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.</p>
```

I tried reinstalling `lighttpd` multiple times, but I get the same error. How could I now run `lighttpd` without causing errors?

Comment: ow my eyes... please replace your html tags with normal formatting. Just add a blank line and then indent the journalctl output instead of this eyesore.

Comment: The journalctl output seems to be completely irrelevant... try systemctl status instead. Or do the normal non-systemd way... run it in debug foreground mode. For example  /usr/bin/lighttpd -D -f /etc/lighttpd/lighttpd.conf  and then you'll see the output of the program itself.

Comment: Find the path of lighttpd rather than guessing... try "which lighttpd" to see if it's in PATH, or use dpkg -L lighttpd | grep bin  or grep through the .service file or init script.

Comment: btw. also in the added output, you can see the path is /usr/sbin/lighttpd which ought to be in root's PATH

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Okay, I see in the new output there that this is a known bug. See https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/lighttpd/+bug/1453463

The text I looked for was:

```
undefined symbol: FAMNoExists
```

And the suggested workaround there is:

```
sudo apt-get install gamin
```

Comment: Had the same issue on Ubuntu 15.10 as well, and this worked. Thanks!